# Wrong Colors after sheet is copied

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro, which does copy a specific sheet from a master workbook to a newly created one. The Problem which occurs is, that the formatting is colored wrong into the new worksheet. For example: If A1 in the first sheet (master Workbook) has the value "no error" and the font color is set to green, in the sheet of the newly created workbook the font Color is orange. This also does happen with some cell backgrounds,which do are manually formated (not conditional). If cell A2 does contain "error" and the font and Background Color is set to red (based on conditional formatting) the format is copied correctly into the new workbook.
Looping through all columns with wrong colors is not an option.

**What I have tried**:

- PasteSpecial (formats),
- set Color theme of new workbook to the old one with vba (didn't got that to work)

**Findings**:

- The wrong coloring only occurs, when the sheet is copied to a new workbook
- I have read that this error might occur because of a different Color template in the new workbook, however i was not able to Change the theme
- The formatting gets wrong with the line `ws.Copy After:=wbFile.Worksheets(1)`, so formatting dependencies based on other Subs do not lead to the wrong coloring

I really appreciate any help or guidance. Thank you.

```
Public Sub saveKonsoData()
Dim strDir As String
Dim wbFile As Workbook
Dim File As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error GoTo fehler

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strDir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\XYZ"
    If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir strDir
    End If

Set wbFile = Workbooks.Add

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(konsoName) 'konsoName is a string Constant

ws.Copy After:=wbFile.Worksheets(1)


File = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\XYZ\" & Format(Now, "YYYY.MM.dd hh.mm") & "_" & "NEWWORKBOOK" & ".xlsx"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


wbFile.SaveAs File
wbFile.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Die Speicherung war erfolgreich.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
Exit Sub

fehler:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Die Speicherung der konsolidierten Datei war nicht erfolgreich. Bitte speichern Sie die Datei manuell.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

I stumbled over the possibility of using *xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme*. I copied the cells instead of the Sheet and used the above mentioned constant. This solved the Problem. The changed codesnipped can be seen below.

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(konsoName)

'ws.Copy After:=wbFile.Worksheets(1)
''TEST STARTS
ws.Cells.Copy

wbFile.Worksheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, _ 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
''TEST ENDs
```

Comment: I wrote 8 mins ago, how i solved my Problem, which i had yesterday. But thank you for advise.

Comment: Yes I didn't see the edit. Glad you did solve it.